# Recover encrypted home directory: login passwd changed, mount passphrase lost

Tags: password, encryption, home-directory, password-recovery, passwd

I have made an extensive research through the site before submitting a new question, but on one side I'm a huge noob and on the other side non of the previous queries seems to fit my case.

I'll try to be as precise and concise as possible, hoping someone has a solution for my problem.

I tried to restore my old Ubuntu partition a few days back. I had an old laptop working with double boot HDD between WinXP and Ubuntu 14.04 in it, but about one year ago I couldn't resist to try Win8 and installed it over the WinXP partition. It obviously screwed up the boot loader but I didn't find the time to do the boot-repair untill now. Problem was that the LOGIN password didn't seem to work anymore. I say 'didn't work' instead of 'was forgotten' because I usually use the same Login password for all my users in all my OSs but the machine didn't accept it anymore.
After trying a list of about 20 variables (I usually use my stickers for inspiration when choosing the login password, i.e. my password should have been *intelRceleronRinsideTM* or *SUSElinuxenterprisedesktop* or *HPsixhundredthirty* or some variarion of those) I thought that the login passwd must had been deleted during the Win8 install [but then again, I'm a **huge noob**]. So... I changed it from terminal using the *passwd* command.
Now, as you might imagine, I can't log in anymore. When I type the right password at the login prompt, the GUI simply refreshes with no further explaination.

I understand that it might be a quite common problem, but all the other people had the decency to backup the mount passphrase somewhere safe but I, being the HUGE noob that I am, simply put it in a txt file INSIDE the encrypted partition... *like locking the key of a safe inside the safe itself*.
I know better now, but I still need to recover the **INVALUABLE** content of the encrypted folder now and I'm starting to get desperate.

I tried all the usual steps which are suggested in cases like these, but not knowing the oringinal login password and having the mount passphrase lost, everything was uneffective.

> TL;DR:
>   My Home folder is encrypted and I need to recover the content. The original login password has been changed throug 'passwd' command, and the mount passphrase backup is lost.

**PLEASE HELP.
PRETTY PLEASE.**

PS: *I can list all the failing methods I tried if necessary.*
PPS: *Sorry for bad english.*

Comment: There is no way without the passphrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of encryption is to make it impossible to access data without the passphrase.

So there is no way to restore your data if you lost it.

Comment: Isn't there a way, having the actual login password, to visualize an history file of previous passwords? Does anything like that exist?
I think that if I had the chanche to recover the password, I might be able do recover the mount

Comment: Recovering the password is not a problem, but you will not get access to the encrypted partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password/24024?s=1|0.0000#24024

Comment: It's not like I need to simply change it... That's the procedure I followed the first time, screwing things up. I just wanna know what my PREVIOUS password is, if there's a way

Comment: No, there is no way to get your previous password.